# R12/timeout error deploying multi-page dash app to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

Trying to learn the ropes of Dash and have made this toy dashboard to display solutions to the heat equation. The single page version deployed to heroku works fine but I'm getting this timeout error with the multi-page version (see logs below). It works fine locally.

I made what I understand to be the necessary changes to get it to deploy properly, namely to change the procfile from app:server to index:server and then import app.server into index.

I tried assigning the server in index versus importing from app and tried adding this line (server.secret_key = os.environ.get('secret_key', 'secret')) that popped up in a few posts I found of people with similar problems.

I also added some print statements to index and it doesn't seem like the server ever makes it inside.

github link: https://github.com/mackwn/dashdiffeq

Below is my logs from Heroku from right after I get the 'build succeded' message:

```
2020-05-22T12:49:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-22T12:49:31.741895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-05-22T12:49:39.870656+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:49:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-22T12:49:39.924058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 30 seconds of SIGTERM
2020-05-22T12:49:39.927273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2020-05-22T12:49:40.109385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-05-22T12:50:48.940059+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:50:48 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10)
2020-05-22T12:50:48.940250+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:50:48 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11)
2020-05-22T12:50:48.981714+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:50:48 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-05-22T12:50:49.199462+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:50:49 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
.....(this kind of keeps going on until I try to load a page)
2020-05-22T12:55:22.232394+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:55:22 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] 2 workers
2020-05-22T12:56:22.333270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=dashdiffeq410.herokuapp.com request_id=22145128-27cc-4397-a615-9916c6cfc286 fwd="71.142.111.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-22T12:56:52.575355+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:52 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:100)
2020-05-22T12:56:52.575554+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:52 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:101)
2020-05-22T12:56:52.673002+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:52 +0000] [100] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 100)
2020-05-22T12:56:52.784718+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:52 +0000] [101] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 101)
2020-05-22T12:56:53.206573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:53 +0000] [118] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 118
2020-05-22T12:56:53.279766+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:53 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] 1 workers
2020-05-22T12:56:53.284164+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:53 +0000] [119] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 119
2020-05-22T12:56:53.313027+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:56:53 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] 2 workers
2020-05-22T12:56:54.373035+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dashdiffeq410.herokuapp.com request_id=2cb221f7-3c14-4397-b0b1-e596037a17ed fwd="71.142.111.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-22T12:58:23.565869+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:58:23 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:118)
2020-05-22T12:58:23.572088+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-22 12:58:23 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:119)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Running the function for solving the differential equation was taking too long on the server which caused the timeout. The development server didn't care how long it took to run the math to generate the plot. Solve the problem by only letting users select inputs that would not cause time outs and would also make sure the page was reasonably responsive.